# Biblatex: cite two-author papers as (A & B <date>)

Tags: biblatex

I'd like biblatex to cite like this:

1. One author papers: "Wood 2007"
2. Two author papers: "Wood & Newborough 2007"
3. Three or more authors: "Wood et al. 2007"

I can't figure out how to get citation styles like "Wood & Newborough 2007" for two author papers. I'm using the authoryear style.  (edit: please note that **I don't want "Wood; Newborough 2007"** but instead I want "Wood & Newborough 2007" or "Wood and Newborough 2007")

Setting `maxcitenames=1` satisfies my requirements 1 and 3 but not my requirement 2 because `maxcitenames=1` causes two-author papers to be cited like "Wood et al. 2007" and I want both authors to appear in the citation.

Setting `maxcitenames=2` cites two-author papers as, for example, "Wood; Newborough 2007" which is *almost* what I want.  But I don't like the semicolon!  If I could replace the `";"` with an `" &"` for two author papers then I'd be happy!

(By the way, just in case this affects the solution: I like having `uniquelist=false` so that biblatex disambiguates citations of different papers by the same first author in the same year by adding a letter after the date like "Wood 2007a", "Wood 2007b")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biblatex can easily be configured to work like you want.
`\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~\&~}` should do the trick. You should add `maxcitenames=2` to your `biblatex` options.

Comment: awesome, thank you - that works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use as options : `maxcitename=2, mincitenames=1`.

This way, any list of more than `2` authors will be truncated to `1` author.

If you want to have the same feature also for references, use `maxnames=2, minnames=1` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply!  Unfortunately setting `maxcitename=2, mincitenames=1` appears to behave exactly the same as setting just `maxcitename=2`.  i.e. two-author papers are cited as "Wood; Newborough 2007" but I want "Wood & Newborough 2007" (i.e. I want the ";" replaced with an "&")